# Заполнение двумерной матрицы в python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, numpy

Добрый день, я только начинаю изучать python и, в частности, разбираю задачу по нахождению вхождения определённых слов в предложении.
Как наиболее красиво с точки зрения python 2.7 можно описать предложенный ниже текст?

```
import numpy as np
sfArray=np.zeros((len(sfSentences),len(sfDict)))
print len(sfSentences)
i=0
for Sentence in sfSentences:
    j=0
    for Word in sfDict:
        Wordlist=Sentence.split()
        sfArray[i,j]=Wordlist.count(Word)
        j=j+1
    i=i+1

print sfArray
```

Я пока не очень разобрался с lambda функцией и похожими конструкциями питона, поэтому буду рад любым советам

Comment: Вся прелесть таких библиотек как NumPy, Pandas, etc. в "векторизированном" подходе - т.е. в использовании готовых функций (часто написанных на C/Cython и оптимизированных по производительности и использованию памяти) вместо цыклов. Наиболее красиво, по-моему, будет воспользоваться библиотекой [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/), которая как раз для таких вещей и создавалась. [Вот пример нахождения наиболее популярных слов в тексте](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40208231/5741205), который использует NLTK и Pandas.

Comment: @MaxU Да, спасибо, покурю NLTK - выглядит интересно